# SQL Group By Question

Tags: sql

I have a table that has the below columns.

I need to find out those people that has More than 2 ApplicantRowid with same jobcategoryrowid and AssessmentTest should have atleast one row NULL with Different Appstatusrowid's.

The result should look exeactly like the below table.

```
Rowid    ApplicantRowid    JobCategoryRowid AssessmentTestRowid AppstatusRowid
10770598    6952346        157                3                     5
11619676    6952346        157               NULL               6
```

Comment: I suggest re-writing this question in a way which would help us answer it. What do the source tables look like? What does the data look like? What are the column types?

Comment: .. and what have you tried already?

Comment: What is the sample input data for the requested output

Comment: What database server is this for?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from
(
    select ApplicantRowid, JobCategoryRowid
    from tbl
    group by ApplicantRowid, JobCategoryRowid
    having count(AssessmentTestRowid) < count(*)
       and count(distinct AppstatusRowid) > 1
) x
inner join t on t.ApplicantRowid = x.ApplicantRowid
            and t.JobCategoryRowid = x.JobCategoryRowid
```

COUNT does not include NULLs, so `count(AssessmentTestRowid) < count(*)` ensures there is at least a NULL

`count(distinct AppstatusRowid) > 1` ensure there are different AppstatusRowids